# Subconsultation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

How to do this subquery I started doing it with IN but I was investigating and changed it to `INNER JOIN` but it still makes me wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, date_nac, CURDATE ()) AS age 
FROM patient 
WHERE date_nac 
INNER JOIN (
    select count(patient id) as Quantity 
    from patient 
    group by age 
    order by Quantity desc limit 6
);
```

Show me this error:

> Error Code: 1235. This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
>   IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Can you describe in plain english exactly what query you are trying to do? That will help me out tremendously.

Comment: I'm trying to get the amount of all patients sorted by age.

Comment: I want to know how to properly place the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your syntax for calculating age is correct, you can use something like this:

```
Select age, count(age)
From
(SELECT  distinct patient_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_nac, CURDATE ()) AS age 
FROM patient
) a
Group by age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use aggregation:

```
select
    timestampdiff(year, date_nac, current_date) age,
    count(distinct patient_id) no_patients
from patient
group by age
order by no_patients desc
```

If there are no duplicate `patient_id`s in the `patient` table (as it should be), you can use `count(*)` instead of the more expensive `count(distinct patient_id)`.

I am speculating that you want the top 6 most populated ages only: if so, you can just add `limit 6` t the end of the query.